# JOIN 2 Tables on 1 Table and Select their separate quantity

Tags: mysql

Is there any other way i can display the `quantity` field i have from 2 different tables where their ID's are referenced on 1 table.

Example:

**shipment_box** table, columns: shipment_box_id, box_code, quantity, date_created

**shipment_consumable** table, columns: shipment_consumable_id, shipment_box_id, item_id, date_added

**shipment_unit** table, columns: shipment_unit_id, shipment_box_id, item_id, date_added

The requirements would be:

- The user must be able to create a shipment box.
- The created shipment box must be able to accept a mix of unit and consumable items.
- The report generated must display all shipment box's contents and quantity per item_code.

Below would be a visual representation of my database tables:
[image: item table]

[image: shipment_box table]

[image: shipment_unit table]

[image: shipment_container table]

my initial idea was to create a separate `SELECT` Query for `shipment_unit` and `shipment_consumable` joining to `shipment_box` but if there's a way i can do this around without having to `UNION` these two queries, it would be more ideal.

below is my draft query **(not tested yet)**:

```
SELECT
    sb.box_code,
    i.item_code,
    COUNT(su.shipment_unit_id) 'Qty'
FROM
    shipment_box sb
JOIN
    shipment_unit su
ON
    su.shipment_box_id = sb.shipment_box_id
JOIN
    item i
ON
    i.item_id = su.item_id
GROUP BY
    sb.box_code,
    i.item_code

UNION

SELECT
    sb.box_code,
    i.item_code,
    COUNT(sc.shipment_unit_id) 'Qty'
FROM
    shipment_box sb
JOIN
    shipment_consumble sc
ON
    sc.shipment_box_id = sb.shipment_box_id
JOIN
    item i
ON
    i.item_id = sc.item_id
GROUP BY
    sb.box_code,
    i.item_code
```

i was thinking of something similar to a hypothetical query like below:

```
SELECT
    sb.box_code,
    i.item_code, -- Display item_code from joined item table
    IF(COUNT(su.shipment_unit_id) = 0, COUNT(sc.shipment_consumable_id)) 'Qty' -- Display quantity of shipment_unit and shipment_consumable items
FROM
    shipment_box sb
JOIN
    shipment_unit su
ON
    su.shipment_box_id = sb.shipment_box_id
JOIN
    shipment_consumble sc
ON
    sc.shipment_box_id = sb.shipment_box_id
JOIN
    item i
ON
    (
        i.item_id = su.item_id
    OR
        i.item_id = sc.item_id
    )
GROUP BY
    sb.box_code,
    i.item_code
```

i am open with a lot of ideas that can help me please. Thank you.

Comment: There is only one `quantity` column in your tables,but you do have 'Qty' in the queries *based on a count* which is all very confusing. I think you question is unclear. It would be much simpler if you provided data in a reusable format (avoid using images of data) but also very importantly: the "expected result" (based solely from the sample data provided).

Comment: @used_by_already apologies. the goal is to count the contents of a box per item_id. but i was looking for a workaround where i don't and won't have to union two queries

Comment: Out of curiosity, why divide the shipment items between two tables in the first place? It's not as though `shipment_unit` were referencing a `unit` table, and `shipment_consumable`, a `consumable` table. Instead, they both are referencing the `item` table, so what's preventing you from having just `shipment_item`? What is the problem that this division is solving?

Answer (score 2):

First, let's sum up a few assumptions:

- It appears that a given item cannot be both a consumable and a shipment unit, unless `item_code` is not a unique value in `item`.
- The `shipment_unit` table is a simple list of all "unit" items in all shipment boxes; `shipment_consumable` is (similarly) a list of all "consumables" in all shipment boxes.
- Both `shipment_unit` and `shipment_consumable` have no `quantity` column of their own; so, if a given shipment box was supposed to have (say) 1 Windows phone and two wired headsets, you would have to have two rows in `shipment_consumable` for the box, with the same `shipment_box_id` and `item_id`.
- You are looking for the items and quantities in 1 instance of a `shipment_box`, rather than the total items and quantities in the total `quantity` of the `shipment_box`. That is to say, if `shipment_box.quantity` is 17, and the box contains 2 Windows phones, you want `2` as the count, not `34` (2 * 17).

First - I must say that there appears to be absolutely no reason to have both `shipment_unit` and `shipment_consumable`. The tables appear to have the exact same structure, and foreign keys to the *exact same other tables* (`shipment_box` and `item`). You know whether a given item is consumable or a "unit" form the item table, so there's no good reason I can see to separate the two things from each other. I feel obligated to point this out, as I suspect your design would be much simpler with just one table (`shipment_content`, perhaps).

Similarly, having a `quantity` field for each `item` in a `shipment_unit` (or `_consumable`, or `_content`) seems like an obvious plus; barring different values for `date_added`, there's no good reason to have:

```
 shipment_unit_id | shipment_box_id | item_id |   date_added
------------------+-----------------+---------+------------------
         7        |        4        |    1    | 2017-10-11 00:00
         8        |        4        |    1    | 2017-10-11 00:00
```

in order to get two Windows phone in the same `shipment_box`. This may not seem likely at this point, but to me it seems like a trivially predictable need for the future. That said, some would say if you don't need it as part of the current plans, leave it out rather than cluttering your design with what could become a bunch of unused fields.

---

That said, we don't always have the option to choose certain elements of the design - you may be stuck with this table layout, through no fault of you own.

So, if this is how it all works, and if it's how it *must* work, how do you get the info you need? I think your draft query would work accurately, and your `JOIN` query would not (except for degenerate cases, where there's 0 or 1 rows for a given `shipment_box_id` in each of the other two tables).

As written, there's one potential issue with your `JOIN` query - it may not be relevant, but it should be noted. You are performing an `INNER JOIN` to both `ship_unit` and `ship_consumables`. If a `shipment_box` only had "unit"-type items in it, then you would get back no data for it - because as written, there must be at least one "unit" *and* at least one consumable for a `shipment_box` to be displayed.

To avoid this, we should make the joins `LEFT JOIN`s, so we get a `shipment_box` even if it's only got units or consumables, but not both (Note that by doing this, we'll also get a `shipment_box` that has no items attached. If necessary, we can filter those out later.)

The next thing to understand is how joins work. Each row in the underlying result set will have the fields from `shipment_unit`, *and* the fields from `shipment_consumable`. If you'll always have *at most* 1 row from each table, things will work as you expect; otherwise, they won't.

Let's posit a `shipment_box` (`shipment_box_id` = 5, `box_code` = 'BX-255', `quantity` = 10) with the following contents:

- 1 Windows phone (unit)
- 1 wired headset (consumable)
- 1 wireless headset (consumable)

So, `shipment_unit` has:

```
 shipment_unit_id | shipment_box_id | item_id |   date_added
------------------+-----------------+---------+------------------
         10       |        5        |    2    | 2017-10-12 00:00
```

and `shipment_consumable` has:

```
 shipment_consumable_id | shipment_box_id | item_id |   date_added
------------------------+-----------------+---------+------------------
           14           |        5        |    3    | 2017-10-12 00:00
           15           |        5        |    4    | 2017-10-12 00:00
```

If we join `shipment_box`, `shipment_unit`, and `shipment_consumable` as you indicate, we get the following (I've left out the `shipment_box` columns, and the `shipment_box_id` and `date_added` from the other two tables, for readability):

```
 shipment_unit_id | su_item_id | shipment_consumable_id | sc_item_id
------------------+------------+------------------------+------------
         10       |     2      |           14           |     3 
         10       |     2      |           15           |     4
```

Basically, since there's no criteria to tie records from `shipment_unit` and `shipment_consumable` together, we get the cross-product of the records from each of those table that match our current `shipment-box`.

When we go to match `item` rows to what weve already got, we see that each row will match two items - the `shipment_unit` item, and the `shipment_consumable` item. So, with `item_code` attached, we've got this:

```
 shipment_unit_id | su_item_id | shipment_consumable_id | sc_item_id | item_code
------------------+------------+------------------------+------------+-----------
         10       |     2      |           14           |     3      |  ITM-002
         10       |     2      |           14           |     3      |  ITM-003
         10       |     2      |           15           |     4      |  ITM-002
         10       |     2      |           15           |     4      |  ITM-004
```

So, when we group by `item_code` there are two rows with 'ITM-002', and we'll get a count of 2 for that item (even though only one is in the `shipment_box`).

There are a couple of ways to work around this.

Since, as I noted above, there's really no reason to have separate `shipment_unit` and `shipment_consumable` table, you can use a union of the two tables within your existing query, instead of getting the `UNION` of two completely different queries:

```
SELECT
    sb.box_code,
    i.item_code,
    COUNT(*) `Qty` -- Display quantity of items
FROM
    shipment_box sb
JOIN
    (SELECT shipment_box_id, item_id FROM shipment_unit
     UNION ALL
     SELECT shipment_box_id, item_id FROM shipment_consumable
    ) AS box_item
ON
    sb.shipment_box_id = box_item.shipment_box_id
JOIN
    item i
ON
    box_item.item_id = i.item_id
GROUP BY
    sb.box_code,
    i.item_code
ORDER BY
    box_code,
    item_code
;
```

This way, in our example, the subquery would generate three rows - 1 from `shipment_unit`, and 2 from `shipment_consumable`.

Of course, that solution still includes a `UNION`. So, if you don't like that, then we can ignore counting the items from our result set altogether, and make simple separate queries to get the counts:

```
SELECT
    sb.box_code,
    i.item_code, -- Display item_code from joined item table
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM shipment_unit su2 INNER JOIN item i2 ON (su2.item_id = i2.item_id)
      WHERE su2.shipment_box_id = sb.shipment_box_id
        AND i2.item_code = i.item_code
    ) +
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM shipment_consumable sc2 INNER JOIN item i2 ON (sc2.item_id = i2.item_id)
      WHERE sc2.shipment_box_id = sb.shipment_box_id
        AND i2.item_code = i.item_code
    ) as `Qty`
FROM
    shipment_box sb
LEFT JOIN
    shipment_unit su
ON
    su.shipment_box_id = sb.shipment_box_id
LEFT JOIN
    shipment_consumable sc
ON
    sc.shipment_box_id = sb.shipment_box_id
LEFT JOIN
    item i
ON
    (
        i.item_id = su.item_id
    OR
        i.item_id = sc.item_id
    )
GROUP BY
    sb.box_code,
    sb.shipment_box_id,
    i.item_code
ORDER BY
    box_code,
    item_code
;
```

Note that we have to add `sb.shipment_box_id` to the `GROUP BY`, since we're using that for the `SELECT COUNT(*)` subqueries.

This is making a number of allowances:

- It will work even if `item_code` is not unique (for instance, if you have `item_id` 27 that's a unit, and `item_id` 31 that's a consumable, but (since they're actually the same thing) both rows have `item_code` 'ITM-027')
- It should work if the above situation is true, and (for some bizarre reason) you've got a box with `item_id` 27 in `shipment_unit`, AND `item_id` 31 in `shipment_consumable`. Since it's counting the occurences in both tables regardless, it would correctly generate a count of 2 for `item_code` 'ITM-027'

If (as I would tend to assume) every `item_code` has one and only one `item_id`, We can avoid the extra `SELECT COUNT(*)` queries altogether.

```
SELECT
    sb.box_code,
    i.item_code, -- Display item_code from joined item table
    CASE i.item_type
      WHEN 1
        THEN COUNT(DISTINCT su.shipment_unit_id)
      WHEN 2
        THEN COUNT(DISTINCT sc.shipment_consumable_id)
      ELSE NULL
    END as `Qty`
FROM
    shipment_box sb
LEFT JOIN
    shipment_unit su
ON
    su.shipment_box_id = sb.shipment_box_id
LEFT JOIN
    shipment_consumable sc
ON
    sc.shipment_box_id = sb.shipment_box_id
LEFT JOIN
    item i
ON
    (
        i.item_id = su.item_id
    OR
        i.item_id = sc.item_id
    )
GROUP BY
    sb.box_code,
    i.item_code,
    i.item_type
ORDER BY
    box_code,
    item_code
;
```

Here, we use `i.item_type' to determine what value to`COUNT`, so we need that in the`GROUP BY`.

We're back to basing our `COUNT` on our result set. As noted before, we could see our incidence of unit or consumable items multiplied through the `JOIN`. However, we're not counting the rows directly; we're counting the number of *distinct* IDs from `shipment_unit` or `shipment_consumable`. This factors those multiple rows right back out again, and we'll get correct counts.

Finally, here's a [DB-Fiddle link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/AK4eC52RvCQz3thngj4uZ/1) showing your two queries (tweaked slightly so the work), and my three, in action.

I'd recommend my 2nd query (`COUNT` via sub-queries) if `item_code` is not unique, and my 3rd (`COUNT DISTINCT`) is it is unique.